# Switching to input mode in vi and unix

Tags: unix, vi

Im trying to switch to input mode from command mode using input commands, such as o, which adds a blank line. However I keep getting "command not found." I'm really just trying to add in some blank lines and was trying to switch to input mode to do so. Any ideas on what went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**command mode** -- Invoked by default on entering vi. Invoked from input mode or last line mode by pressing the ESC key.

**input mode** -- Invoked from command mode by pressing the desired input key (see "entering text" below).

**last line mode** -- Invoked from command mode by pressing Shift-colon (:).

**Entering/Deleting Text:**
   (Must be entered from command mode. Puts you in input mode.)

```
a -- append after cursor 
A -- append at end of line 
i -- insert before cursor (most commonly used to start new file) 
I -- insert at beginning of line 
o -- create new line below the current line 
O -- create new line above the current line

(Must be in command mode.)

dd -- delete current line, 3dd deletes 3 lines 
D -- delete from cursor to end of line 
u -- undo last change 
x -- delete character at cursor, 4x deletes 4 characters
```